# Redirecting pages

Tags: php, redirect, base-url

case:

homepage
   -dropdown menu
      -item1 - going to select item1
      -item2
      -item3

item page
    - shows item1 content and hides the contents of item2 and item3

(action)-going to select another item, say item2

problem: item page still shows item1's content not item2 yet the url address now change to
         www.website.com/itempage#item2
it only shows the content of the item selected when i'll refresh the page like clicking f5

this is my code in calling the page.

```
   <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'ProductItem', 
                                            'action'=>'index')); ?>#callplus">Call Plus</a>
```

Comment: Whats the resulting HTML?

Comment: what do you mean by resulting html?..

Comment: i just called the id of the div for it to show it's content since each div is hidden..

Comment: Sounds more of a js problem. You need to show more code!